# Ag-grid onSelectionChanged property doesn't allow to use useState component, in case of checkboxSelection, the checkbox doesn't get checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, checkbox, ag-grid-react

Here is the detail code. I am adding checkbox selection and using useState component to set the selected nodes when selection is changed but the checkbox is never selected when useState component is used in onSelectionChanged method.

```
const PluginGrid = (props) => {
    const gridApi = useRef(null);
    const searchString = useRef('');
    const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
    const isRTL = getContext(({ RTL }) => RTL);

    // The datagrid captures the change event and i need something to force this component to update so the save button en/dis-able works correctly
    const rowSelection = () => {
        // issue is here, in using setSelectedRows useState components
        setSelectedRows(gridApi.current.getSelectedNodes());
    };

    const addPlugins = () => {
        let plugins = gridApi.current.getSelectedNodes().map((node) => node.data);
        props.addPlugins(plugins);
        props.close();
    };

    const rowActionClick = (params) => {
        props.deletePlugin(params.data);
    };

    const deselectAll = () => {
        const selectedNodes = gridApi.current.getSelectedNodes();
        setSelectedRows(selectedNodes);
        gridApi.current && gridApi.current.deselectAll();
        setSelectedRows([]);
    };

    const multiRowsDelete = () => {
        const selectedNodes = gridApi.current.getSelectedNodes();
        selectedNodes.forEach((plugin) => props.deletePlugin(plugin.data));
        gridApi.current && gridApi.current.deselectAll();
        setSelectedRows([]);
    };

    const isSaveDisabled = () => {
        if (!gridApi.current) {
            return true;
        }

        if (selectedRows.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    const getFilteredPlugins = () => {
        return props.plugins.filter((plugin) => {
            if (plugin.type === props.type) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    };

    const getGridScopeValue = (params) => {
        switch (params.value.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'common': {
                return formatMessage('shared');
            }

            case 'site': {
                return formatMessage('site');
            }
        }
    };

    const filterChange = (data) => {
        searchString.current = data;
        gridApi.current.onFilterChanged();
    };

    const isExternalFilterPresent = () => {
        if (searchString.current && searchString.current !== '') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    const doesExternalFilterPass = (node) => {
        const { data } = node;
        for (let icol = 0; icol < gridApi.current.columnModel.columnDefs.length; icol += 1) {
            const col = gridApi.current.columnModel.columnDefs[icol];
            let value = data[col.field];

            if (col.field === 'scope') {
                switch (data.scope.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'common': {
                        value = formatMessage('shared');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (value) {
                value = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                if (value.indexOf(searchString.current.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    const getInlineRowActions = (params) => {
        let compactMode;
        if (params.agGridReact !== undefined && params.agGridReact.props.compactMode === true) {
            compactMode = true;
        } else {
            compactMode = false;
        }
        const overflowModifiers = { offset: { offset: '0, 2' } };
        const tooltipProps = {
            placement: 'bottom',
            trigger: ['hover', 'focus'],
            fallbackPlacements: ['top', 'right', 'left'],
            modifiers: overflowModifiers,
        };

        const inlineActions = [
            <HorizontalMoreButtonItem
                onClick={() => rowActionClick(params)}
                aria-label={formatMessage('delete')}
                key={`delete-${params.rowIndex}`}
            >
                {
                    <Tooltip {...tooltipProps} tooltip={formatMessage('delete')}>
                        <HorizontalMoreButtonItemIcon
                            style={
                                compactMode
                                    ? {
                                          width: '1.75rem',
                                          height: '1.75rem',
                                          'min-width': '1.75rem',
                                      }
                                    : {}
                            }
                        >
                            <Icon src="sitebuilder/static/images/delete.svg" />
                        </HorizontalMoreButtonItemIcon>
                    </Tooltip>
                }
            </HorizontalMoreButtonItem>,
        ];

        if (params.data.scopeQualifier !== props.siteDef.name) {
            return null;
        }

        if (params.data.scope.toLowerCase() === 'common') {
            return null;
        }

        return inlineActions;
    };

    const getColumnDefs = () => {
        return [
            {
                headerName: formatMessage('site.configuration.plugin.grid.column.name'),
                field: 'name',
                suppressSizeToFit: true,
                headerCheckboxSelection: true,
                headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
                checkboxSelection: true,
            },
            {
                headerName: formatMessage('site.configuration.plugin.grid.column.category'),
                field: 'category',
            },
            {
                headerName: formatMessage('site.configuration.plugin.grid.column.scope'),
                field: 'scope',
                valueFormatter: getGridScopeValue,
            },
            {
                headerName: formatMessage('site.configuration.plugin.grid.column.scopeQualifier'),
                field: 'scopeQualifier',
            },
            {
                type: 'actionColumn',
                field: '',
                pinned: isRTL ? 'left' : 'right',
                cellRendererParams: {
                    moreButtonProps: {
                        'aria-label': 'More',
                    },
                    horizontalMoreButtonProps: {
                        'aria-label': 'More',
                    },
                    getInlineRowActions,
                    isDynamic: () => true,
                    getProgressIndicator: () => (
                        <MoreButtonItem
                            style={{ height: `${MENU_ITEM_SIZE * 3}rem` }}
                            role="progressbar"
                            aria-valuetext="Loading"
                            aria-valuemin={0}
                            aria-valuemax={NUMBER_ITEMS_IN_LIST}
                        >
                            <MoreButtonItemProgressIndicator
                                style={{
                                    height: `${MENU_ITEM_SIZE * 3}rem`,
                                    width: '100%',
                                    paddingLeft: '0rem',
                                }}
                                size={`${MENU_ITEM_SIZE}rem`}
                                strokeWidth={4}
                            />
                        </MoreButtonItem>
                    ),
                },
            },
        ];
    };

    return (
        <div className="plugin-grid-container">
            <DashboardGridFilter update={filterChange} />
            <div className="plugin-grid-container__grid">
                <>
                    <MultiSelectToolbar
                        show={selectedRows.length > 1}
                        style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: 1 }}
                    >
                        <MultiSelectToolbarLeft>
                            <Typography>
                                {selectedRows.length} {formatMessage('selected')}
                            </Typography>
                            <MultiSelectToolbarDivider />
                            <Button
                                onClick={() => {
                                    deselectAll();
                                }}
                            >
                                {formatMessage('deselectall')}
                            </Button>
                        </MultiSelectToolbarLeft>
                        {selectedRows.some((node) => {
                            if (node.data.scopeQualifier !== props.siteDef.name) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            if (node.data.scope.toLowerCase() === 'common') {
                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        }) ? null : (
                            <MultiSelectToolbarRight style={{ marginRight: '17px' }}>
                                <Tooltip
                                    placement="bottom"
                                    trigger={['hover']}
                                    fallbackPlacements={['bottom', 'right']}
                                    modifiers={[{ name: 'offset', options: { offset: [0, 15] } }]}
                                    tooltip={formatMessage('delete')}
                                >
                                    <IconButton
                                        aria-label={formatMessage('delete')}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            multiRowsDelete();
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Icon src="sitebuilder/static/images/delete.svg" />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </Tooltip>
                            </MultiSelectToolbarRight>
                        )}
                    </MultiSelectToolbar>

                    <DataGrid
                        rowSelection="multiple"
                        wrapperProps={{
                            style: {
                                height: 'calc(100% - 50px)',
                            },
                        }}
                        columnDefs={getColumnDefs()}
                        onGridReady={(params) => {
                            gridApi.current = params.api;
                            gridApi.current.sizeColumnsToFit();

                            let propertyKey;
                            if (props.type === 'js') {
                                propertyKey = 'jsPluginLocations';
                            } else {
                                propertyKey = 'cssPluginLocations';
                            }

                            gridApi.current.forEachLeafNode((node) => {
                                if (props.siteDef[propertyKey]) {
                                    const selected = props.siteDef[propertyKey].find(
                                        (plugin) => plugin === node.data.location
                                    );
                                    if (selected) {
                                        node.setSelected(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }}
                        onSelectionChanged={rowSelection}
                        suppressContextMenu
                        rowData={getFilteredPlugins()}
                        isExternalFilterPresent={isExternalFilterPresent}
                        doesExternalFilterPass={doesExternalFilterPass}
                    />
                </>
            </div>
            <div className="plugin-grid__upload-button">
                <Button onClick={props.showUpLoad} style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>
                    <ButtonText>{formatMessage('site.configuration.plugin.upload')}</ButtonText>
                    <ButtonIcon>
                        <Icon src="sitebuilder/static/images/upload.svg" />
                    </ButtonIcon>
                </Button>
            </div>

            <span className="plugin-grid__line" />
            <div className="plugin-grid__buttons">
                <div className="plugin-grid__button">
                    <Button onClick={props.close} style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>
                        <ButtonText>{formatMessage('cancel')}</ButtonText>
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="plugin-grid__button">
                    <Button
                        variant="call-to-action"
                        onClick={addPlugins}
                        disabled={isSaveDisabled()}
                        style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}
                    >
                        <ButtonText>{formatMessage('add')}</ButtonText>
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I am trying to set the selected nodes in useState component so that it re renders on checkbox selection changed. And also use the selected rows for other features like MultiSelectToolbar, etc. components which will required re render. So used useState component to store the selected nodes but the check box is not working as expected, it is not getting checked. Also it doesn't throw any error in the console. I tried using useRef component instead of useState but useRef is not allowing a re render when check box selection is changed. Any help will be appreciated.

Using Ag-Grid version 30.2.0

Here is the screenshot of this issue.
[Issue with the check box not getting checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCcP0.png)